# Vs Code Extentions: vscode.window.activeTextEditor always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to get the currently opened document in vscode extensions using the `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` property. I however get undefined each and every time.

```
 this._panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(
      async (msg: any) => {
        switch (msg.command) {
          case "startup":
            const _currDoc = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
            console.log({ _currDoc });
            const doc = vscode.workspace.textDocuments[0];
            const data = doc?.getText();
            this._panel!.webview.postMessage({
              command: "data",
              data,
              fileName: path.basename(doc?.fileName),
              type: doc?.languageId,
            });
            break;
          case "opened":
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
      null,
      this._disposables
    );
  }
```

> Does anyone have any idea why is this behaviour happending because in the `extention.ts` file i can be able to see the current opened document.

Comment: When this code runs, does your webview has gained focus? Or the Text Editor still is focused?